# Why does the breaker trip when I try to use the burners on my gas stove?

Tags: gfci, gas, oven, circuit

My Frigidaire gas stove (Model: FFGF3054TS) keeps tripping my GFCI circuit breaker when I try to use the top burners. I tried turning the oven on and that works, but every time I try to use the top burners the circuit trips. This stove is only 3 years old.

I did run the cleaning cycle last week and the stove worked fine after that. We pulled the stove out and everything worked and pushed it back into its space and then things stopped working again.

The main outlet that the stove gets plugged into is behind the unit and that outlet connects to another GFCI outlet. There is nothing else on this circuit when it trips.

---

We pulled the stove out and it's still not working. Oven works but burners trip the GFCI. We even tried another outlet.yes there are electric igniters.

Comment: "pushed it back into its space and then things stopped working again" Sounds like you may have pinched the cord or, possibly, damaged the outlet. What happens if you pull it out from the wall - will the top burners work then?

Comment: Sounds likely that there is a ground fault in the stove, or specifically the spark-ignitor circuit for the top burners.

Comment: Does the breaker have a TEST button?  If so can you post the model number if visible? Any designation such as AFCI or GFCI?

Comment: I take it your stove has spark-ignited burners?

Answer (score 2):

It is common for older stoves (and probably some newer ones) with spark igniters to arc to a ground path.

The stove does precisely the thing that GFCI/AFCI devices are intended in protect from: They arc.

Your stove should probably be connected to a circuit without these protections if possible.

Comment: Although this is likely true, there is the possibility the top burner has a connection fault. Maybe energizing the oven chassis? In this case, this suggestion might turn out dangerous to OP, if they don't realize it. That's especially important to call out as many future gas oven owners may read this answer and one may end up with a faulty one.

Answer (score 2):

The appliance repair came out and tested the stove. He plugged it to a NON -GFCI line and it works fine. He even tested the load and the oven pulls a bigger load then the burner igniters and it didn't blow the circuit breaker. The stove only blows when plugged into ANY GFCI lines and the igniter is turned on for the burners. He tried 1 other GFCI line in the house and the stove blew that too. The gas stove is on the other side of the kitchen (>6ft from the water source/sink) so he was not sure why a GFCI line was put on this outlet. Solution: remove the GFCI outlet and replace with a regular outlet. Stove works fine.

Comment: Yeah, since the outlet isn't serving a kitchen *countertop surface*, the NEC doesn't require it to be GFCI protected.  (Same for the outlet behind the fridge.)

Answer (score 1):

There's something wrong with the electric igniters. It may be easy to find -- there are maintenance manuals in the web for most recent brands/models -- or it may be time to call someone in to service it. I presume you're out of warranty, or you'd just let the company correct it.